# Issues dragging elements in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

Are there any reasons why an image would not be draggable in Firefox even when the attribute `draggable="true"`? I'm designing an image swapping script in JS but am having some problems when running it in Firefox. While the code works fine in Chrome, Edge, and IE, when I try and drag and drop an image in Firefox it doesn't appear as if the browser is letting me drag the image (no ghost image appears) and thus my drag event isn't firing or triggering any of the drop events. I am generating the image via `document.createElement('img')` and setting the attributes with

```
imgElement.setAttribute('draggable', true);
imgElement.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)');
```

my drag function:

```
function drag(ev) {
 if (!ev.target.classList.contains(clickClass)) {
  return;
 }

 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
 document.getElementById(ev.target.id).parentElement.setAttribute('class', 'noclick');
};
```

I read in a different question that the drag event may not fire in Firefox if data isn't being transferred, however, that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Please provide a working example (not only parts of code). This will be the best way to get help. You can use http://jsfiddle.net for that, or create a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I created a jsfiddle and it seems to work in the jsfiddle but not on the site. Would it be ok if I deleted this post as it appears the problem might not be related to JS?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `imgElement.setAttribute('ondragstart', 'drag(event)');` you should add the `dragstart` listener instead:

```
imgElement.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
    drag(e);
});
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle and it seems to work in the jsfiddle but not on the site. Would it be ok if I deleted this post as it appears the problem might not be related to JS?

Comment: If you delete this post I will not get the votes from it. Is there any reason to delete it? I think the answer ist correct...

Comment: I can leave it up, its just that the problem doesn't seem to stem from the Javascript itself. That is, when I plugged my old code into the jsfiddle it had the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in Firefox, at least in v61, setting the `draggable` attribute to `false`, instead of `true` will give you the desired result - allowing the image to drag along with the movement of the mouse.

```
element.setAttribute('draggable', false);
```

It *may* be that Firefox assumes it will handle the dragging of images, unless you explictly set an attribute to `false`, in which case you use your own js handler to move the image yourself.

It also seems Firefox resets the attribute back to `true` by default once the initial movement has occurred and the mouse button released. The `draggable` attribute must be reset back to `false` to start the process all over again. But, that shouldn't be a problem considering you're likely handling all mouse events for that image, and can easily insert a line of code to ensure that dragging is `false` when you need it to be.